# java fxml load exception

Tags: java, javafx

i am doing following code. I want My Qwerty.fxml to display Show.fxml file on button click. Here is the code:

**Qwerty.fxml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import java.lang.*?>
  <?import java.util.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="qwerty.Qwerty">
<children>
    <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
    <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Main.java**

```
package qwerty;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
 import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
 import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class Main extends Application {

private Stage stage;

private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 390.0;
private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500.0;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("FXML Login Sample");
        stage.setMinWidth(MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        stage.setMinHeight(MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        gotoLogin();
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

  private void gotoLogin() {
    try {
        Qwerty login = (Qwerty) replaceSceneContent("Qwerty.fxml");
        login.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void gotos() {
    try {
        ShowController login = (ShowController) replaceSceneContent("Show.fxml");
        login.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml)  {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource(fxml));
    AnchorPane page = null;
    try {
        page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
    Scene scene = new Scene(page, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    return (Initializable) loader.getController();
}
}
```

**Qwerty.java**
    package qwerty;

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class Qwerty extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {



private Main application;


public void setApp(Main application){
    this.application = application;
}


@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
application.gotos();

}

public void processLogin(ActionEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

**Show.fxml**

```
 <?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import java.util.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller=".ShowController" />
```

**Exception generated**

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Qwerty/dist/run405710440/Qwerty.jar!/qwerty/Show.fxml:9

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:976)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:738)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at qwerty.Main.gotos(Main.java:65)
at qwerty.Qwerty.handleButtonAction(Qwerty.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .ShowController
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:925)
... 71 more
```

I am getting FXMl load exception. I am new to java and fxml. Please help

Comment: What's the exact exception? Please, copy it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> I cannot find a FXML controller named ".ShowController" which is
>   defined in /qwerty/Show.fxml FXML file at line 9.

If Show.fxml has not any controller then  delete `fx:controller=".ShowController"` from it.

Answer (score 2):

I had same error. You need to add the package_name to the below controller path

```
fx:controller=".ShowController"
```

this needs to be like this

```
fx:controller="package_name.ShowController"
```